# Pre-image of affine subspace under T in Hom(V,W)

Tags: linear-transformations

The text (Advanced Calc, Loomis and Sternberg) says that the pre-image under T (linear) is either empty or an affine subspace itself. I am stumped as to how to prove this (since T is not always 1-1 and so the inverse relation is not a mapping)   --- and I can't visualize under what circumstances this pre-image is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The preimage of a subspace is empty if this subspace does not intersect the image. Consider an affine transformation that projects the plane on the x-axis. Then the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ having $y = 1$ has empty preimage.

The preimage of subspace $A$, if not empty, is always a subspace. Let $B = f^{-1}(A)$, and $b_i \in B$, so $f(b_i) = a_i \in A$. Also, let $\lambda_i$ be such that $\sum \lambda_i = 1$. Take an affine combination of $b_i$: $b = \sum \lambda_i b_i$. Consider $f(b) = f\left(\sum \lambda_i b_i\right)$. Since $f$ is an affine transform, it preserves affine combinations, so $f\left(\sum \lambda_i b_i\right) = \sum \lambda_i f(b_i) = \sum \lambda_i a_i$ - this is an element of $A$, since a subspace is closed under affine combinations. Since $f(b) \in A$, we have $b \in f^{-1}(A)$. We proved that the preimage is closed under affine combinations, which means that it is an affine subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the image of $T$ is the $x_1$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ and you ask for the preimage of the line $x_2=3$?